# PHP EXEC and C++ program that continuously outputs

Tags: php, c++, command-line, exec

Is it possible to use PHP function EXEC with a C++ program that outputs a result every 500 milliseconds?

I don't think it is possible because i think EXEC waits for the code to finish and then grab the result. But if it is possible can you please tell me how?

and if not, what other options do i have ?

Comment: have a look at proc_open()

Comment: still with it i have to wait for the whole c++ code to terminate and then i can take the output

Comment: i've looked around and the best way to do this is through sockets